# Ошибка типа SyntaxError: missing VK API

Tags: javascript, json, vkontakte-api

Получаю следующую ошибку при выполнении кода

`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement      friends.get:1:11`

```js
<script>
var call= $.getJSON(
  'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=123456&fields="nickname"$callback=?', 
  function (resp) {
     console.log(resp.response[0].first_name);
  }
)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильный запрос будет таков, во-первых nickname без ковычек, во-вторых, callback [без знака доллара](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests).

```
var call = $.getJSON('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=123456&fields=nickname&callback=?', function(resp) {
    alert(resp.response[0].last_name + ' ' + resp.response[0].first_name);
});
```

Вообще пробуй так, более грамотно обрабатывать ошибки, успех и прочее:

```
$(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=123456&fields=nickname&callback=?',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp.response[0].last_name + ' ' + resp.response[0].first_name);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });

});
```